# Unequal load on WebSphere clustered nodes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, load-balancing, ibm-mq

Our Java EE application runs in a clustered Websphere environment.
It picks message from MQ queue and processes it.

- MQ on Node 1

Node 1 processed 10000 Transactions. Time per req was 30 millisec.
Node 2 processed 95 Transactions. Time per req was 780 millisec.

---

- MQ on Node 2

Node 1 processed 9500 Transactions. Time per req was 35 millisec.
Node 2 processed 100 Transactions. Time per req was 850 millisec.

Can anyone tell why the node 1 always processes more transactions. Is there any setting or configuration to be adjusted to equally share the load?

Comment: Is your Q manager also clustered? Or do both nodes connect to the same Q manager? You might want to check server session configuration for each of the activation spec.

Comment: Both the nodes connect to same q manager. Can you tell me what to check in server session configuration of the activation spec?

Comment: Please check "Activation specifications > Your Specification > Advanced properties". The property name is "Maximum server sessions"

Comment: what value should I set here in the Maximum server sessions?how does it relate to my problem?

Comment: If the value is same for both the nodes it means it has equal number of threads to process messages. Although it does not ensures that both processes equal requests, but there should not be such huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be relative server weights causing the routing differences. In the admin console, go to "Servers > Clusters > [your cluster type] > [your cluster name]" then under the "Additional Properties" heading click "Cluster members".

Set their "configured weight" to equal values and then ripplestart the cluster (or cycle individually).  Note, "runtime weight" takes effect immediately but is reset to configured weight whenever the server is started.

Requests are allocated by a simple formula: (weight of Member X) / (Sum of all member weights)

so if server A has a weight of 20 and server B has a weight of 1, then server A should get 20 / (20+1) or 95.3% of all requests.